# Google sheets tip calculator and tax estimator

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having trouble getting google sheets to do what I want it to do.

1. I have a form that adds new rows into a google sheets spreadsheet
2. The entries are then further manipulated in new columns that don't correlate to the google form.
3. I wanted 3 columns of deductions to be subtracted from 1 column being a daily intake
   a. example:
   [] gForm:Daily bank(A) | gForm:Credit Cards(B) | gForm:Tip outs(C) | gForm:Total Cash(D) | Column E
   1        30                      30                    40                   200              100
   2
   3
4. I want each line in Column E to automatically populate the code in each new row, that takes column D and subtracts A:C and spits out the difference in Column E.
   code example idea: =sum(D:D-sum(A:C))
5. I made this an Array formula: Below
   =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(G:G)=1, "Total Taxable Cash", IF(ISBLANK(F:F), "", ArrayFormula(F:F-(sum(C2:E2))))))

PROBLEM is that it takes every cell in colums A:C and then subtracts each row in Column D to spit out incorrect answers in Column E.

Does anyone know how to code this so that it adds the code automatically to each new row but also calculate each row individually and not as columns.

Please help me, thank you all.

Comment: Forneça um exemplo de sua necessidade para que possamos melhor entender!

Comment: Please provide an example sheet with some data explaining what do you want to happen. Your explanation here is a bit confusing and could lead from misinterpretation from our part.

Answer (score 0):

Michael, your examples in your post are inconsistent. You reference A:D and SUM(C:D), but then your formula example uses G, F and SUM(C2:E). I'll assume that your formula is correct and your example data above it is wrong.

I also don't clearly understand your goal. But at a guess, try this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1, "Total Taxable Cash", IF(F:F="",,F:F-(C:C+D:D+E:E))))
```

I've written out some inefficiency and redundancy. But the key change is just swapping your `SUM(C2:E2)` with `(C:C+D:D+E:E)`.